# Can't pip install packages in Anaconda

Tags: python, macos, pip, anaconda

I broke conda somehow by updating it. If there was a package pack that I couldn't get using

```
conda install pack
```

I could do

```
pip install pack
```

and everything worked great. That package would then be accessible from the python in anaconda/bin/python.

After running conda update conda, pip corresponds not to the conda environment but to the base python on osx (I think).

```
 which pip
 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

I tried navigating to the pip package in the anaconda folder. But even running

```
 pip install pack
```

from there installs the package in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages and not in //anaconda. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Edited:

```
 which conda
 /Users/Ben/anaconda/bin/conda

echo$PATH
```

bash:echo/Users/Ben/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin://anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Ben/anaconda/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin: No such file or directory

Comment: please add the output of `echo $PATH` and `which conda`

Comment: @cel. added. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try `conda update pip` or `conda update -f pip` to force it.

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of the original OS python pip, use:

With **Debian**/**Ubuntu**:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
```

With **Redhat**/**Centos**/**Fedora**:

```
sudo yum remove python-pip
```

That was referenced here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187701/how-do-i-correct-the-path-for-pip